# Why doesn't this really simple blank white screen saver work? (It's black)

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, screensaver

I'm trying to make a simple macOS screen saver via Objective-C in XCode that just fills the whole screen with white.  (Because of [this](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT2807?viewlocale=en_US).)  Simple, right?  I thought so too, but no matter what I do, I get a blank, black screen.  It doesn't seem like my drawRect method is even getting called.  Any idea what I'm missing?

```
#import "Blank_WhiteView.h"

@implementation Blank_WhiteView

- (id)initWithFrame:(NSRect)frame isPreview:(BOOL)isPreview {
    [super animateOneFrame];
    [self setNeedsDisplay:YES];
    return self;
}

- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)rect {

    [super drawRect:rect];
    CGContextRef context = (CGContextRef) [[NSGraphicsContext currentContext] graphicsPort];
    CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
    CGContextFillRect(context, NSRectToCGRect(rect));
}

- (BOOL)hasConfigureSheet {
    return NO;
}

@end
```

Comment: Can you run this with xcode and put a break point in the drawRect method to see if it gets called?

Comment: You could also do the drawing like this [NSColor.whiteColor set]; NSRectFill(view.bounds);

Comment: Thanks, Mark.  I really wish that I could.  I do suspect that the drawRect is never getting called, but apparently there is no (straightforward) way to run a screen saver in the debugger.  And I tried your exact drawRect suggestion earlier today also and that does the exact same amount of nothing.  It seems like I'm missing something about how the ScreenSaverView base class works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ScreenSaverView` draws everything through `-animateOneFrame`. To be able to use `-drawRect` (and in your situation, you should, because you aren't animating anything) implement `animateOneFrame` such that:

```
- (void)animateOneFrame {
    [self setNeedsDisplay:YES]; // -drawRect will be called next draw loop
}
```

This way, `-drawRect` will be called when appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Quartz composer or even the picture screensaver might be good non code ways to do this.